PXE booting a KubeVirt VM
I have a use case to PXE boot a number of KubeVirt VMs. I'm looking for some guidance on how to set this up :)
From what I understand I need a separate network connected to the VMs. Set up on the k8s nodes, but outside of k8s. Network that will:

span across k8s nodes
connect the Kubevirt VMs via multus
allow for my custom IPAM to operate in

Should I go with something like https://medium.com/@technbd/multi-hosts-container-networking-a-practical-guide-to-open-vswitch-vxlan-and-docker-overlay-70ec81432092 or is there another way ?
Like let https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/ovs-cni do all the magic ?
what do you recommend ?
